# AngularJS, how to trigger dom-related javascript on ng-if change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form field (input text) with an ng-if being false at the begining. At some point the ng-if value become true.

When this happen, I want to execute some javascript which manipulate the DOM. To keep it simple, let's say that I need to select the input value and focus the field.

```
<input type="text" ng-value="foo" ng-if="show" onshow="doSomething()"/>
<button ng-click="toggle()"></button>
```

The JavaScript

```
ctrl.foo = "bar";
ctrl.show = false;

ctrl.toggle = function(){
    ctrl.show = !ctrl.show;
}
```

I know that it looks like a "non-angular approach", but here I think the action is not model related.

Comment: you could create a directive that and place it on your input like : `do-something="show"`. When `show` is true, the directive runs. It would be similar to ng-if since when show is true, ng-if renders the html.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `ng-if` directive execute the template each time `show` become true, you can use `ng-init` for that. See the following snippet and replace `alert('test);` by anything you want.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('test', function($scope, $element) {

  $scope.show = false;
 
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
  
  $scope.init = function() {
    alert($element.find('input').val());
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="test">
    <input type="text" value="foo" ng-if="show" ng-init="init()" />
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's smart! But as init is an angular function, it shows me the model context and not the dom (input tag), or at least I don't know how to acces it. If possible that way, can you update your init function to execute focus() on the input dom object?

Comment: I am still not convinced. $element is the controller dom element. In my real-life case, my controller contains a two dimensional dataset, so to reach the specific element, I would have to generate unique id's for each and search. It really looks the wrong way to search back the element that trigged the event from the outer controller context, even if it is doable.

Comment: In this case you'll have to create your own directive to replace `ng-init`

Comment: And that directive would be able to reach the input element directly? How?